# More Symmetric than the symmetric groups?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, symmetric-groups, normal-subgroups

So I was considering the following question.

Is there a group of size n! (or less), that contains a larger number of subgroups than $$S_n$$? In thinking about this problem one obvious contender that came to mind is if we consider the largest power of 2 less than or equal to n! then we have the group   $$ \Bbb{Z}_2 \times \Bbb{Z}_2  ... \Bbb{Z}_2  $$.

Naturally this has $$\ge 2^{\lfloor\log_2(n!)\rfloor}$$ different subgroups (from selecting some combination of crossing the subgroups $$\Bbb{Z}_2$$.

But do there exist ways to create even more subgroups than that? An example that came to mind was

$$ G_1 \times G_2... $$ whereas the total number of subgroups of this group obeys (let $O(G)$ denote the number of subgroups of G)

$$ O(G_1 \times G_2... \times G_n) \ge  \times O(G_2) ... \times O(G_n)$$

So that was one layer of analysis, but here's another question, that follows up naturally.

Do there exist groups of size n with more unique subgroups than the symmetric group?

Comment: I think the question you should be asking is if there's a group of size at most $n!$ that has more subgroups than $S_n$. Comparing a group of size $n$ with $S_n$, which has $n!$ elements, isn't fair.

Comment: A yes! thank MJD for that

Comment: Note that the formula you give for the number of subgroups of a direct product is wrong. In general, many of the subgroups sit "diagonally" in the direct product and cannot be obtained as direct product of subgroups of the factors. For example, in $\mathbb{Z}_2^2$, there are three subgroups of order $2$, the two "obvious" ones, and a diagonal one. (So there are 5 subgroups in total, whereas your formula gives 4.)

Comment: Thank you @verret, i made a note of inequality. It seems that was a subtler counting problem than I naively assumed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it is known that the number of subgroups of an elementary abelian $2$-group is larger than the number of subgroups of a symmetric group of roughly the same order.

For reference, the corresponding OEIS sequences are:

https://oeis.org/A006116

and

https://oeis.org/A005432

In particular, you can see that, already, the elementary abelian $2$-group of order 64 has 2825 subgroups while the one of order 128 has 29212. By comparison, the symmetric group of order 120 only has 156.

Asymptotically, the number of subgroups of the elementary abelian group of order $2^n$ grows like $c^{n^2}$ (from the OEIS page) while the number of subgroups of the symmetric group of order $n!$ grows at most like $d^{n^2}$. Since $n!$ is much larger than $2^n$, it should be an exercise to deduce the result from this.

(The constant $c$ is actually known, while bounds on $d$ are known, in case this is useful.)

Comment: Good answer, but did you actually count different subgroups or all subgroups?

Comment: You're going to have to be clearer about what you mean by "different". (Up to conjugacy? Up to conjugacy in the automorphism group?)

Comment: unique, as was meant in the question.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand your comment. I'm giving the number of "all " subgroups which, to me at least, seems to be the same as the number of "different" subgroups. (If by "different" one means "unequal".) Again, what does "unique" mean here? Please use some mathematical terminology to clarify...  (Up to isomorphism, etc..) In any case, you can just, from the references I gave or even the functions involved, it should be clear what is being counted.

Comment: I can't read the mind of the asker, but he talks about unique and different groups. I highly suspect it has to do with isomorphism.

Comment: I can't read the mind of the OP either, but why are you asking me if I am counting "different subgroups or all subgroups" if you can't explain what the differences between these are?

The counts I am giving are for all subgroups, which is the most obvious interpretation of the OP, IMO.

Note however that the OP is muddled in more than one way, for example, the number that he gives for the number of different subgroups of an elementary abelian $2$-group is wrong, for all interpretations of "different" that I can think of. (The reasoning he gives for the number is flawed as well.)

Comment: Okay. Lets just wait what the OP says.

Comment: @wythagoras,   so when I posed the problem, I was thinking in terms of the total raw number of groups, not discounting equivalence up to isomorphism. Based on the answers to this question I was going to dig around, see what I could find, and then pose that as the most natural follow up. This answer matches my intuition, although my actual calculations and motivation were flawed.

Answer (score 4):

No. Since any group with order $n$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $S_n$ (Cayley's theorem), and any subgroup of a subgroup is a subgroup of the original group.

Comment: The question has been corrected so that this answer is no longer pertinent.